# SharePoint 2010 RealWorld Samples

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have seen 101 on ASP.NET and C# and many other sample real world applications on ASP.NET.

I am trying to find out if there are any similar Samples available for SharePoint 2010. Mostly around creating deploying SharePoint components (not custom web parts of course).

Comment: What do you mean by "SharePoint components"?  I would consider a custom web part to be a component, but it seems you mean something different.  Do you mean Page Layouts? Event receivers? Something else?

Comment: @Peter: I meant basic SharePoint Components like PageLayouts, List Instances with Event Handlers, ContentTypes, Site Page, etc. I think Custom WebParts can vary to any extent, but a hello world all these (may be including Custom WP) will be great to understand and extend upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the SharePoint Guidance content from Microsoft.  I hear it is really good.  I know some of the people that developed it so I believe it is good.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203468.aspx